# Adding extra column to user_permission pivot table not syncing correctly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I use `spatie-permission` in my project what i am trying to do is to add to the `model_has_permissions` pivot table an extra column `branch_id` because i want each user to have permission for specific **branch** but the problem here is, for example, i add a record like this

| permisson_id | model_type | model_id | branch_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | App\Models\Seller | 1 | 1 |

when I try to add the same permission with the same user **but with a different branch** it overwrites the old record instead of creating a new record

here is the code that has the problem

```php
$this->user->permissions()->syncWithPivotValues($this->selectedPermissions, ['branch_id' => $branch->id], false);
```

Comment: `sync()` (and I assume `syncWithPivotValues()`) only looks at the `permission_id` column to determine if a new record should be created or overwritten. If you have, for example, `permission_id: 1, branch_id: 1`, and you want to add `permission_id: 1, branch_id: 2`, that will overwrite the old when using `sync()`, as there is already a record with `permission_id: 1`, so it won't add another one. I haven't used this package, but it looks like a `many-to-many`, which is a pivot between 2 tables. You're trying to add a 3rd table, and allow repeated `permission_id`s, but that won't work by default.

Comment: yes, you are correct there a way to allow it to repeat this record?

Comment: That I'm not too sure about to be honest... Your solution (now edited out) will allow duplicated values, but I'm not sure if that will have any functionality issues moving forward. You might need to change this to a `hasMany()`, where a User can have many Permission/Branch combinations, but in the context of `spatie-permissions` package, that also may not work. I'm afraid I only know the "why" of this question, and not the "how to fix it", sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->user->permissions()->sync([
    $this->selectedPermissions => ['branch_id' => $branch->id]
]);
```